# Magento 2.4.6 Tiny_mce_5 Editor not working

Tags: javascript, magento, tinymce, magento2, text-editor

Magento 2.4.6 version with porto theme not allow me to modify content from Editor. We only able to add HTML/css/Js code. Show/Hide button not showing. And there is errors in console. Sharing screenshot with this message. Is it Magento default issue or some server configuration issue ?[text]([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaDYw.png))

Tried to add lower version of Tiny_mce but they are depriciated in latest version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to conflicts with any other extension like pagebuilder. If you are using such extension disable that and check